# Not Printing anything on screen

Tags: python, function, printing

```
def even_number_list(even_list):
    for i in even_list:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            return True
        else:
            pass
        
even_number_list([1,3,5,6,9])
```

This code is not printing anything on the screen, I believe that it should print True, please help a beginner.

Thanks,

I think I'll get an output, True

Comment: This program has no output. The function returns a value, but you're not doing anything with it. As a side-note, you should probably return `False` from the function if no even number is found (after the loop). The `else` statement is pointless and can be removed completely.

Comment: Note that this will return True if any number in the list is even, not if all numbers are even (but perhaps that's your intent). As to your question, you can either add a print() in your function, call it with print(even_number_list([1,3,5,6,9])), or call it from your Python console (which will print its return).

Answer (score 0):

Your function, as you expect, should return `True`. But when you call it, you don't use the return value. If you want to print the return value, you need to call `even_number_list()` inside of a `print()` function to print the output or assign the function call to a variable.

```py
def even_number_list(even_list):
    for i in even_list:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            # Return True if one even number is found
            return True
    # Return False if all numbers in even_list are odd
    return False

# Call function even_number_list() returns True but is not assigned to anything
even_number_list([1,3,5,6,9])

# Assign return value to output
output = even_number_list([1,3,5,6,9])
# Print the output
print(output)

# Or in one step:
print(even_number_list([1,3,5,6,9]))
```

I also removed your `else` condition, as the `pass` statement does nothing.
And in addition, if no even number is found your function returns `False` now.